# Automatic Migration with EntityFramework.Migrations gives Error with Renaming but not with SqlMigrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Im using `EntityFramework` and `EntityFramework.Migrations` to implement solution using Code-First and Automatic Migrations.

Wherever i made a very simple test solution to test the Migrations capabilities and i`m stuck and renaming simple properties.

i have this entity :

```
  public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when i try to rename `FullName to FirstName`, I understand i have to use Update-Database with renames so i type this in the Console:

```
 Update-Database -Renames:"Customer.FullName=>Customer.FirstName"
```

Now this used to work when i was using "`SqlMigrations`" but now that i Use "`EntityFramework.Migrations`" it doesn't work, it gives me this error:

```
Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Renames'.
At line:1 char:26
+ Update-Database -Renames: <<<< "Customer.FullName=>Customer.FirstName"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Database], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseComma 
   nd
```

So i bet its different in `EntityFramework.Migrations`, Im not sure what im doing wrong or what i should be doing...

Here is Resources i have been reading about both:

- [EntityFramework.SqlMigrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-walkthrough-of-august-2011-ctp.aspx)
- [EntityFramework.Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-with-magic-walkthrough-automatic-migrations.aspx)

Comment: You may want to check another EF Code-First migration library [EntityFramework.SchemaCompare](http://github.com/kriasoft/data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The team of EntityFramework.Migration has confirmed that this features has been deprecated and its not in the last Beta-Build for `EntityFramework.Migrations`